# Why the number of non-zero singular values is $n-1$ for $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ when $n\ll m$

Tags: linear-algebra, singular-values, principal-component-analysis

There's a statement in the paper [Phatak (1997)](https://analyticalsciencejournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/%28SICI%291099-128X%28199707%2911%3A4%3C311%3A%3AAID-CEM478%3E3.0.CO%3B2-4)

> In most spectroscopic problems, the number of non-zero singular values is $n-1$ for $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ when $n\ll m$. Consequently, at most $n-1$ principal components can be extracted.

Can anyone explain why the number of non-zero singular values, in this case, is $n-1$ instead of $n$, and if this condition is only limited for spectroscopic problems?

Thank you.

Comment: Presumably because the structure of the spectroscopic problems leads to some linear dependency between the rows of $X$; but you are limiting the audience that can answer your question if you do not say more about what these spectroscopic problems are.

Comment: It's just a one-off statement in the paper. That's why I'm confused about the context and if it applies to most of the real-life practical problems.

Comment: In many applications, the number of nonzero singular values is actually far less than $n$. Many complex phenomenon are approzinately low-rank https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/18M1183480

Comment: Thanks for the reference